# shell - Yes no prompt not working using case

Tags: bash, shell

I am using bash 4.2 to create a prompt

```
        read -p "Want to print the output to $newname ? (y/n)" $yesno
        case "$yesno" in
           [Yy])
                   outname=$newname;;
           [Nn])
                   echo "Quitting ...";
                   exit 4;;
           *) 
                   echo "Quitting !!";
                   exit 5;;
        esac
```

The problem is that whether I give y or n, the output is `"Quitting !!"`

But if I comment the case `*)`, the result equates `outname` to `newname`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To evaluate a bit on the response by Ivan, since `yesno` does not have a value by the time you execute the `read` command, `$yesno` expands to the empty string, and `read` does not see a variable name where to store the results. In this case, the string being read is stored on the variable `REPLY`. Your example would have worked if you had written `case $REPLY in....`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable name in `read` have to be without `$`

```
read -p "Want to print the output to $newname ? (y/n)" yesno
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. 2 things I have fixed in OP's code.

i- We need NOT to put `$` while reading value from user in variable `yesno`.

ii- I have changed user's entered input to small letters so no need to check both the `y|Y` or `n|N` responses here.

```
read -p "Want to print the output to $newname ? (y/n)" yesno
case $(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "$yesno") in
y)
   outname=$newname
   echo "In y condition here...."
   ;;
n)
   echo "Quitting ..."
   exit 4
;;
*)
   echo "Default Quitting !!";
   exit 5
   ;;
esac
```

When I run above code:

```
./script.ksh
Want to print the output to  ? (y/n)y
In y condition here....
```